# How to develop a Docusaurus documentation with Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, docusaurus

I want to be able to develop a [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) based documentation only by using Docker as local development environment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have setup a Docusaurus documentation, for example by following https://docusaurus.io/docs#fast-track

1. Start a NodeJS Docker container with mounted documentation sources, connect/jump into it:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name documentation -v ${PWD}:/home/app \
    -w /home/app -p 3000:3000 -u node node:lts /bin/bash
```

2. Within the running container, install and run Docusaurus:

```
node@63f99bab33ed:/home/app$ npm install
node@63f99bab33ed:/home/app$ [...]
node@63f99bab33ed:/home/app$ npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0 --no-open --poll 2000 // See https://docusaurus.io/docs/cli for details
[...]
[SUCCESS] Docusaurus website is running at: http://localhost:3000/
✔ Client
Compiled successfully in 14.34s
```

3. Open http://localhost:3000/ for accessing your documentation

**Disclaimer**

Inspired by [How to Dockerize a Docusaurus v2 application](https://dev.to/cindyledev/how-to-dockerize-a-docusaurus-v2-application-fp7)

Comment: You can even do all this inside of VSCode, therefore pull a git branch to maintain your documentation. Eventually, you may also deploy that Docusaurus deliverable onto GitLab Pages, which typical use case is for a project related static website.